SONiC OS. ACL for ip of vlan interface L3
I'm trying to apply simple acl rules to IP address vlan100, but it always responds to ping.
"VLAN100_ACL": {
  "policy_desc": "VLAN100 Ingress ACL",
  "type": "L3",
  "stage": "INGRESS",
  "ports": [
    "Vlan100"
  ]
}

...
"VLAN100_ACL|DENY_ALL": {
  "priority": "2",
  "PACKET_ACTION": "DROP"
}

So how do I restrict access to services for vlan ip?
I understand that it in one segment and not used any route and packages delivered on level L2.
So far I have found a solution using ssh service control rules.
Here is an example of the configuration:
https://lexxai.blogspot.com/2024/06/simple-basic-setup-of-sonic-os-for.html
https://lexxai.blogspot.com/2024/06/hardware-switch-with-stateless-firewall.html
